# How do I fetch the source file from pytesseract extract

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

So the gist is after I extracted the OCR/tesseract data from a pool of images, I then run `re.findall(r'example')`

How would I fetch the source file that has an "Mountain" word?

It's still a bit vague in my part. Can you help out. Thanks!

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
result = row['text']#from the OCR
file_1 = re.match(r'Mountain', result)
file_2 = re.match(r'Lake', result)
if file_1: 
    print #how do I fetch/get the original file that has the matching word for file_1
```

Comment: Your question is bit vague!! You need to run tesseract on the file which starts with `example` as a word ?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Perhaps a simple example of the pytesseract data you are dealing with? What is the source file you speak of?

Comment: hahaha! sure sure apologies.